# How to use StreamBuilder with Observable?

Tags: dart, rxdart

I'm trying to use StreamBuilder to react to multiple Streams. So, I created an Observable that I'm using to merge them:

`Observable.merge([stream1, stream2, stream3])`

The problem is: I don't know how to make a StreamBuilder to listen to this Observable. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a property in your bloc class:

```
Observable<T> get mergedStream => Observable.merge([stream1, stream2, stream3]);
```

And then use this property as source for **stream** property of StreamBuilder.

Comment: Any idea about, How to dispose this observable?

Comment: Usually `Observables` are in separate BLoC class which must contains `dispose` method. Then you can call `dispose` in any place you need (eg. in `dispose` method of `StatefulWidget`, or as value of `dispose` parameter of `Provider` class (provider plugin is required).